# Ubuntu 20.04 multipath configuration

Tags: server, 20.04, multipath

I just installed a new Ubuntu 20.04 server as a virtual machine on an esx-Server.
When I look into `systemlog` I see lots of multipath entries.

```
multipathd[651]: sda: add missing path
multipathd[651]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
multipathd[651]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
multipathd[651]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory
multipathd[651]: sda: add missing path
multipathd[651]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
multipathd[651]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
multipathd[651]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory
```

I think multipath is just not configured and my question is if I can disable multipath.
Since I checked this on several Ubuntu 20.04 servers multipath is enabled by default.

Does it make sense to activate multipath?

Comment: after I added "blacklist { devnode "sda" }" to /etc/multipath.conf the entries in syslog disapeared. I am still wondering why multipath is enabled by default.

Comment: Works for me, thanks! I also encountered another problem after setting up Ubuntu 20.04 as VM (root partition only 4 GB large), so I guess a few setup routines are a bit buggy :(

Comment: @BurninLeo As far as I know the 4GB root partition is meant to be that small. You can use lvm to grow it to whatever size you like. Its meant to keep most space available for you to create/extend partitions as needed.

Answer (score 58):

Through this, I have resolved my issue:

1. Run `vi /etc/multipath.conf` and add this to the file:

   ```bash
   defaults {
       user_friendly_names yes
   }

   blacklist {
       device {
           vendor "VMware"
           product "Virtual disk"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Restart the `multipath-tools` service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart multipath-tools
   ```

Comment: blacklisting the type of drive feels more concise and makes for the sort of config that you can share around with chef or ansible.

Answer (score 42):

There is a SUSE linux KB on the topic - https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016951. The problem is that VMWare by default doesn't provide information needed by udev to generate */dev/disk/by-id* entries. Apart from ESX, VMWare Workstation (my case) is also affected. The resolution is to put

```
disk.EnableUUID = "TRUE"
```

to the virtual machine definition, i.e. into the **.vmx* file or via *Edit Settings* -> *Options tab* -> *General* -> *Configuration Parameters* in ESX UI.

After rebooting VM with this parameter set, the disk are visible in `/dev/disk/by-id` and multipathd doesn't complain anymore.

Comment: This worked for me on VMware Fusion as well. (You need to right-click the VM file in the Finder and select Show Package Contents to see the .vmx file.)

Comment: I had to power off the VM, and then go to *Edit Settings -> VM Options -> Advanced -> EDIT CONFIGURATION...* in vSphere Client version 6.5.0.

Answer (score 29):

If you dont have access to your host ESX you can add the following lines to your `/etc/multipath.conf` file which also blacklists common other devices like CDRom drives etc.

```
defaults {
    user_friendly_names yes
}
blacklist {
    devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st|sda)[0-9]*"
}
```

Comment: Which is better between editing the VM configuration in ESXi and editing `/etc/multipath.conf` on the VM? Could you please elaborate on advantages and disadvantages of each solution?

Comment: @simlev EnableUUID can cause problems in the context of cloning the guest system

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. It saved me lots of headaches! One small addition: I had to reboot the VM for these changes to take effect.

Comment: This change plus `systemctl restart multipathd` on Ubuntu 20 had no effect. The sdb log errors continue unabated.

Comment: as posted this only covers sda. I changed this to 'sd.' and that shut up sdb too

Answer (score 3):

Adding the below into the guest vm parameters worked for me. The syslog is no longer complaining and the server appears to be staying up.

```
disk.EnableUUID = "TRUE"
```

This is added to the virtual machine definition, i.e. into the `*.vmx` file, or via Edit Settings -> Options tab -> General -> Configuration Parameters in ESX UI.

Ubuntu 20.04 running apache and Wordpress php-7.4-fpm

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a:

```bsh
defaults {
    user_friendly_names yes
}
blacklist {
    devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
    devnode "^sd[a-z]?[0-9]*"
}
```

for `sda`, `sdb`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need multipath, turn it off:

```
systemctl disable multipathd
systemctl stop multipathd
```

Comment: I needed to disable multipathd on a Linode, and found that `apt-get dist-upgrade` was still trying to `systemctl start multipathd`, even with the service disabled.  I did not want to remove the multipathd package, because `ubuntu-server` depends on it.  However, MASKING the service with `systemctl mask multipathd` prevented it from even being STARTED by the package config scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to set it.

Use [govc](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/tree/master/govc)

Setup `GOVC_URL` first like

```
export GOVC_URL='https://username:password@vcenter.company.com/sdk'
```

and set UUID like

```
govc vm.change -e="disk.EnableUUID=TRUE" -vm='MY_VM_NAME'
```

One more thing, you have to poweroff and poweron to take effect this change

```
govc vm.power -off -force VM1
govc vm.power -on -force VM1
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these line in `/etc/multipath.conf`. this works for me all error are gone

```
blacklist {
        devnode "sda"
}
```

Comment: How does your answer add new information to (not just a less general version of) https://askubuntu.com/a/1269917/1004020 ?

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1342224)