# How can I get multipathd to stop monitoring my disk?

Tags: server, multipath

I'm booting Ubuntu server 20.04 from a single nvme disk.
Since a couple of days ago, multipath has been spamming my syslog with these messages:

```
Jun 11 20:10:14 xb multipath: nvme0n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Jun 11 20:10:14 xb multipath: nvme0n1: uid = eui.0000000001000000e4d25c7f117c5001 (sysfs)
Jun 11 20:10:17 xb multipath: nvme0n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Jun 11 20:10:17 xb multipath: nvme0n1: uid = eui.0000000001000000e4d25c7f117c5001 (sysfs)
Jun 11 20:10:20 xb multipath: nvme0n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Jun 11 20:10:20 xb multipath: nvme0n1: uid = eui.0000000001000000e4d25c7f117c5001 (sysfs)
Jun 11 20:11:34 xb multipath: nvme0n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Jun 11 20:11:34 xb multipath: nvme0n1: uid = eui.0000000001000000e4d25c7f117c5001 (sysfs)
Jun 11 20:11:37 xb multipath: nvme0n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Jun 11 20:11:37 xb multipath: nvme0n1: uid = eui.0000000001000000e4d25c7f117c5001 (sysfs)
```

I can get the following list of devices to confirm it monitors my nvme disk:

```
multipathd> show devices
available block devices:
loop1 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
nvme0n1 devnode whitelisted, monitored
loop6 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
loop4 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
loop2 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
loop0 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
loop7 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
loop5 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
loop3 devnode blacklisted, unmonitored
multipathd>
```

I tried the command:

```
remove map nvme0n1
```

But got the message: fail

So now the question is, how can I get it to stop monitoring my nvme disk and spamming the syslog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 multipath configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242731/ubuntu-20-04-multipath-configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the solution was to add blacklist to the file `/etc/multipath.conf` like this:

```
defaults {
    user_friendly_names yes
} 
blacklist {
    devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st|sd|mmc|nvme)[a-z0-9]*"
}
```

This effectively stopped multipath from spamming the syslog.