# Failed to start MySQL Community Server on Ubuntu 20

Tags: mysql

I got the error when starting the VM `Failed to start MySQL Community Server`.

I used `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Thu 2021-01-21 08:45:54 UTC; 1s ago
    Process: 112957 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 112968 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 18626)
     Memory: 472.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─112968 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jan 21 08:45:54 suitecrm.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

Also I used `journalctl -xe`:

```
Jan 21 08:44:29 suitecrm.com multipathd[742]: sda: add missing path
Jan 21 08:44:29 suitecrm.com multipathd[742]: sda: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Jan 21 08:44:29 suitecrm.com multipathd[742]: sda: failed to get sysfs uid: Invalid argument
Jan 21 08:44:29 suitecrm.com multipathd[742]: sda: failed to get sgio uid: No such file or directory
Jan 21 08:44:31 suitecrm.com audit[109486]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/109486/task/109652/mem" pid=109486 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fs>
Jan 21 08:44:31 suitecrm.com kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1611218671.020:624): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/109486/task/109652/mem" pid=109486 comm="mysqld" requ>
Jan 21 08:44:31 suitecrm.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 2.
Jan 21 08:44:31 suitecrm.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 21 08:44:31 suitecrm.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Cmd `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       148G  128G   14G  91% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop2       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10492
/dev/loop4       72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/18884
/dev/loop3       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop6       72M   72M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19009
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

There is nothing in the `/var/log/mysql/error.log` log. How do I start MySQL?

Also I followed the instructions(Run Mysql Server on Safe Mode):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
killall mysqld
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables&
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

In /var/lib/mysql/mysql_error.log I see this:

```
2021-01-21T10:15:18.354232Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010140] [Server] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 10000 (request: 80510)
2021-01-21T10:15:18.354243Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 4745 (requested 40000)
2021-01-21T10:15:18.613490Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2021-01-21T10:15:18.613556Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000076] [Server] option 'slow_query_log': boolean value '2' was not recognized. Set to OFF.
2021-01-21T10:15:18.613574Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010084] [Server] options --log-slow-admin-statements, --log-queries-not-using-indexes and --log-slow-slave-statements have no effect if --slow-query-log is not set
2021-01-21T10:15:18.615324Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 317918
2021-01-21T10:15:18.634165Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-21T10:15:21.604856Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-21T10:15:22.524074Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-01-21T10:15:22.596974Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: fut0lst.ic:86:addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA thread 140434928031488
```

Comment: Have you changed the location of any MySQL files or made changes to AppArmor? 

Comment: @Matigo No, I didn't do anything

Comment: Looks like there's some kind of RAID / storage solution / load balancer or similar in play, judging by the log entries from [multipathd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_DM_Multipath). Maybe this is a virtual machine running on VMWare? Then the problem described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242731/ubuntu-20-04-multipath-configuration) _might_ be the root cause. Something along the lines of "multipathd can't properly address `/dev/sda`, therefore AppArmor can't find some files it expects to find, therefore AppArmor says nope to starting the MySQL daemon".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Yes, I have VMWare. I added `disk.EnableUUID = "TRUE"` into the *.vmx file. But MySQL won't start, same error.